# Another follow the path of relation through the grid

Tags: mathematics, no-computers, grid-deduction

Inspired by Galen's series of puzzles...there is a relation between rectilinear-adjacent squares such that there is a unique rectilinear path from the top-left corner of the grid down to the bottom-right corner of the grid. Each square can participate in the path no more than once. What is the relation and the path it induces?

[image: Puzzle Grid]

Comment: Any comments on my answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Path(Sorry, but I did on my IPad:

> [image]

Relation:

> Difference adjacent numbers is a power of 2

Comment: Perfectly correct!

Answer (score 3):

> [image]
>  Absolute differences between successive terms are all squares.

Comment: yes, this is a path but the relation does not satisfy all of the conditions of the question.

Comment: This path is unique under the given relation; what condition is being violated?

Comment: I think you need to check that again. The path is not unique under the given relation.

Comment: Agh, you're right. There's two paths, and rot13(obgu pbagnva ercrngf fb V'z abg fher juvpu bar vf gur pbeerpg bar, vs rvgure vf.)

Comment: Neither can be correct, since the relation does not produce a unique path. Don't feel bad though, I did my best to bait exactly this trap :-)